# How to format PostgreSQL jsonb_set as a prepared statement

Tags: postgresql

```
var query=`UPDATE "public"."vehicle_ads" 
           SET options=
                   jsonb_set(
                    options, 
                    '{$1, ${subgroup}, -1}', 
                    '{"name": "${optionName}"}'::jsonb
                   )
           WHERE "vehicleId"=${id}`;
```

I'm having the following issues with the above query.  If I replace $1 with ${group}, no error.  But if I leave $1 and pass group as a prepared statement, I get the error...

```
bind message supplies 1 parameters, but prepared statement "" requires 0
```

My goal is to tokenize the entire query, e.g.:

```
var query=`UPDATE "public"."vehicle_ads" 
       SET options=
               jsonb_set(
                options, 
                '{$1, $2, -1}', 
                '{"name": $3}'::jsonb
               )
       WHERE "vehicleId"=$4`;
```

Then...

```
could not determine data type of parameter $1
```

I know I'm lost in a formatting soup of template strings and Postgres, unsure what needs ticks, single quotes, or double.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

Here's what I'm doing with detail.

I have a nested object with vehicle options data stored as a jsonb field.  It has the form:

```
{
  "Group": {
     "SubGroup": [
           {
              "name": string,
              "hasOption": bool
           }
           ...
      ]
      ...
   }
  ...
}
```

I want to edit the name in a sub group.  For instance Powertrain.Drivetrain[0].name='AWD';

Comment: Placeholders within strings won't work (at least with prepared statements). Please try `jsonb_set(options, ARRAY[$1, $2, '-1', 'name']::text[], $3::jsonb)`

Comment: @pozs thanks for giving it a shot...  You exact solution throws `Error: invalid input syntax for type json`.  The first argument of jsonb_set is a jsonb object, second is a text path, third is the new value in jsonb.  I tried `jsonb_set(options, '{' || ARRAY[$1,$2,'-1']::text[] || '}', '{"name": $3}'::jsonb`  but that returns `Error: malformed array literal: "{"`.

Comment: @DWalsh that error message indicates that what you want to set to the `name` property, is not a valid json(b). You could try to convert to json(b) with `to_json($3)` or `to_jsonb($3)`, but it would be helpful to include the parameter types (and perhaps example values for the parameters) in the question.

Comment: @DWalsh my bad, didn't notice that you actually didn't try what I suggested. you need to include the `name` property to the text path, because placeholders for parameters won't work in any literals (so `'{"name": $3}'::jsonb` also won't work)

Comment: @pozs thank you!  You're right, it wasn't working how I expected because it replaced the entire object with the update.  (I didn't catch it because of my React/Redux optimistic update.  Oops) Your way worked!  I edited my original question.  Now that I'm up to speed, I tried this query:  `jsonb_set(options, ARRAY[$1, $2, $3, $4], to_json($5)::jsonb)` and it returned error message `could not determine polymorphic type because input has type "unknown"`.  `jsonb_set(options, ARRAY[$1, $2, $3, $4], "${value}"'::jsonb)` works perfectly

Comment: @DWalsh if all of your array elements are bound parameters, than you probably need the `::text[]` suffix (the explicit cast to a text array) when your database framework / API does not provide a type for bound parameters. Also, that way you need to take care of bounding the `-1` as text/varchar/etc. and not with some numeric type.

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to convert the variable to `text` before converting it to jsonb using `to_jsonb`

```
UPDATE table SET body = jsonb_set(options, '{key}', to_jsonb($1::text));
```